# ReCaptcha validation failed, please try again. How to reset ReCaptcha in checkout?

Tags: magento2, checkout, recaptcha

I'm working with magento 2.4.3-p3 and I want to know to reset reCaptcha in checkout?
In general reCaptcha is working fine but the problems comes when PayPal payment fails and customer wants to try again or customer simply cancel payment and try again without refreshing page - then I'm getting error from `module-re-captcha-webapi-rest/Plugin/RestValidationPlugin.php` that "ReCaptcha validation failed, please try again".
I see that in `module-re-captcha-webapi-ui/view/frontend/web/js/jquery-mixin.js` there are set headers `settings.headers['X-ReCaptcha'] = payload.xReCaptchaValue;` but after payment fails/cancels the value in `payload.xReCaptchaValue` is not refreshed. Any idea how to fix it?
Changing from V2 to V3 doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: Hello @kajtek 

Do you find any solution for above issue?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Sometimes a user selects a Braintree payment and gets an error such as; Your payment could not be taken. Please try again or use a different payment method due to insufficient funds, etc. The if they try again they get this error; Cannot use a payment_method_nonce more than once.

The recaptcha was stopping the Braintree payment method nonce from refreshing and this error would fire - Cannot use a payment_method_nonce more than once.

In my instance I was running M2.4.3-p1 and the payment method was using Braintree.

After much testing I found that the Magento quality patch [MDVA-39305-V2](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-knowledge-base/kb/support-tools/patches/v1-1-1/mdva-39305-login-issues-with-enabled-google-recaptcha.html?lang=en) fixed this issue for me at the checkout. Checkout this link here to learn more about [Magento quality patches](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-knowledge-base/kb/announcements/commerce-announcements/magento-quality-patches-released-new-tool-to-self-serve-quality-patches.html?lang=en)

I hope this helps anyone else with this same issue. I took me many hours to track down the true cause.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue, and I found this patch fixed it for me: [ACSD-50345: reCAPTCHA issues during the checkout](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-knowledge-base/kb/support-tools/patches/v1-1-31/acsd-50345-recaptcha-issues-during-checkout.html?lang=en)